# How to create a filter area by date in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJSAF.png)

I have this table (A3:H16) in google sheets like in the photo above and I want to filter this whole table by 2 dates (from and to) and these 2 dates should be entered by user in F2 and G2 (in yellow background). Whenever "from" and "to" dates in F2 and G2 are changed, the table should be filtered accordingly.
Can you please explain how I can do it using Apps Script?

The google sheet file is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17NsFH90yQCeXy6K5YAKAErHxUZBzROXAGeV_-KBJYCU/edit?usp=sharing
It has dummy data

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! It's recommended that you either share a copy of the file for folks to be able to help, or place the data (dummy one) in a way that can be copied for tests.
this could be accomplished using ```FILTER``` or ```QUERY```.

Comment: Hi! I have the file here that has dummy data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17NsFH90yQCeXy6K5YAKAErHxUZBzROXAGeV_-KBJYCU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a separate sheet, where you inform the date, you use it, adapting to your reality:

```
=iferror(QUERY(Sheet1!A3:H,"select * where todate(F) >= date '"&TEXT(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and todate(F) <= date '"&TEXT(G2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0),"No record found")
```

`QUERY` is a very powerful GSheets function.
In it, you can convert columns' data to Date Format, so it can be compared e.g `todate()`

Then, you make sure that the cell referenced is in the date format as well, by doing the following:
`date` and forcing the cell format with `'"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`

**Reference:**

[Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any way that I can do this auto-filter in the same sheet? For example, I change the date, values also change in this sheet according to the chosen date?

Comment: Only if you apply the filter to the table itself.

Comment: Can you please explain this part please? select * where todate(F) >= date '"&TEXT(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'. I didn't understand quite well. Thanks